# Multilingual issue using django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, multilingual

Im Using python3 and django1.10 for my application , and kinnda new to django.
Im planning to have many languages for django admin panel.
as i follow the rules in [Django documantion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/), i find out that i have to use a `middleware` for localization... here is my setting apps

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

I also add this

```
LANGUAGES = (
   ('fa', ugettext('Farsi')),
   ('en', ugettext('English')),
)
```

and

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

And of course i installed the `GNU gettext` and create my locale folders with `django-admin.py makemessages -l fa` command , then i translate the `.po` file and compile it so i get the `.mo` file.
so far every things looks good i think, and when i just change the language in setting file just by typing it,every thing works.
Now here is my question, How can i add the feature to change the application language from admin panel, or view ?
i add the `url((r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))),` in my `urls` file. But i just dont know what to do now. please help me. What is the next step ? How can i add this form or where sholud i add this form to change language ?

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/next/page/" />
        <select name="language">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a view, you can use:

```
from django.utils import translation

# to change to French for example
translation.activate('fr')

# and you set it in the session to change it for the user
request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = 'fr'
```

So, you can add code similar to that in your view's "form_valid" method, passing in the language code for the language chosen in your form.

For more info on this, check out the docs at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.translation

and also:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language

Comment: i add this code to my view. but when i print out `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` still get the same (en) ... im stock and confused :( @Cody Parker

Comment: Sorry, you also need to change it in the session to manually change it for the user. I've updated my answer to show that.

Comment: im trying to find a way that change it in admin panel. my application dose not have front view or any views...
any suggestion ? also see here [question] (it changes my application language correctly. but it dosent change the language file i also provided. how can i load that language  ? can you help me ? [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102538/language-file-dosent-load-automaticaly-in-django)

Comment: for setting what should i import ? @Cody Parker

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you're looking for where you import settings, you do that with: from django.conf import settings