# language file doesn't load automatically in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, multilingual

I'm using python3 and Django 1.10 for my application, and I am kind of new to Django.
I'm planning to have many languages for Django admin panel. As I follow the rules in Django documentation, I find out that I have to use a middleware for localization... Here are my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
   ('fa', ugettext('Farsi')),
   ('en', ugettext('English')),
)
```

When i go to admin `mylocal/en/admin` or `mylocal/fa/admin` the application language changed perfectly. But my language file(`.po`) always looks into `LANGUAGE_CODE`. when i set `LANGUAGE_CODE='fa'` it will change to farsi . not automatically 
Now i just want that my language files load using the urls `/en/` or `/fa/` .

Here is my `urls.py` file if you need to check out.

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar working setup, the main difference seems to be that I'm using `ugettext_lazy`. That's because I need to translate these strings in my models or settings when they were accessed, rather than when they were called (which would happen only once: they would only be evaluated on server startup and would not recognize any further changes; e.g. switching the Django admin language).

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation

That's what I use (in this special case, german is the default language and I'm translating into english):

#### project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

#### project/settings.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGES = [
  ('de', _('German')),
  ('en', _('English')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

#### app/models.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Kindergarten(models.Model):
    stadt = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(Stadt))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Kindergarten')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Kindergärten')
```

#### Workflow

```
$ python manage.py makemessages --locale en
... edit project/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po ...
$ python manage.py compilemessages
```

Now I can access my translate Django admin (interface + models) via:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/admin/app/kindergarten/
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/app/kindergarten/

#### Notes

- Pyhton 3.5.2
- Django 1.10.2